# Using a message class static method taking in an action to wrap Try/Catch

Tags: c#, lambda, code-reuse

I have a Result object that lets me pass around a List of event messages and I can check whether an action was successful or not.

I've realized I've written this code in alot of places

```
Result result;

try
{
    //Do Something 
    ...

    //New result is automatically a success for not having any errors in it
    result = new Result(); 
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    //Extension method that returns a Result from the exception
    result = exception.ToResult();
}

if(result.Success) ....
```

What I'm considering is replacing this usage with

```
public static Result CatchException(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action();
        return new Result();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return exception.ToResult();
    }
}
```

And then use it like

```
var result = Result.CatchException(() => _model.Save(something));
```

Does anyone feel there's anything wrong with this or that I'm trading reusability for obscurity?

**Edit:** The reason I am trapping all exceptions is I use this code inside of my ViewPresenter classes at any point I interact with my model since if I get an unhandled exception I'd rather display the actual error to the user (internal app) as opposed to just redirecting them the generic error page.

Comment: Updated my answer to add why I'm doing this, probably should've thought of this before posting knowing it was going to be brought up. The messages are always bound to the UI whether success or fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with using a functional approach, and passing in a lambda.  That is perfectly valid.

That being said, I'd question your use in this specific scenario.  Trapping all exceptions into a general purpose "Result" class seems dangerous.  Ideally, you should be catching exceptions which you can handle correctly - not every possible exception and continuing.

That being said, if you really want to do this, I have a couple of suggestions for you:

1) I'd make a static, immutable result for success, and just do:

```
result = result.Success;
```

This avoids generating a new "success" each time you succeed, which hopefully is the most common option.

2) I'd probably avoid the extension method, and do:

```
result = new Result(exception);
```

This will be much more clear and obvious in intent, and there's really no reason to do an extension method in this case...

Comment: Agreed. Far more eloquent than my answer. Nice.

Comment: I'm not really a fan of the immutability that gives me too many flashbacks to EntLib Validation where I need to copy the entire ValidationResult message list into a new List just so I can add my own message to it. If I was going to return something like this through a public API I'd make the Result object immutable entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be catching `Exception` like this. You should only be catching known exception types that you know how to handle.

If you did that, you code would no longer be so repetitive, so there would be no case for using this pattern for re-usability.

All round this looks like a very bad idea, not just the lambda pattern, I'm talking about the handling of exceptions by converting them into results objects. You are basically allowing yourself to ignore all exceptions and continue working. There is a reason why C# error handling is done with exceptions and not with return codes, and that is because exceptions allow for structured, hierarchical and call stack based handling. Unless you have simplified the code for this question, I would reconsider your exception handling process.

---

In general though, I don't see anything wrong with the lambda pattern. I use something similar myself for wrapping multiple retries of a code block. But in this case I don't think it's what you need.

Comment: +1 Agreed. You need to catch a specific business-logic-oriented exception to ensure you don't pass other information to the end user. Its a security risk.

Comment: -1 I'm not ignoring the error, I'm presenting it to the user, instead of "ERROR". As the question said this is an internal app.

Comment: @Chris, my point was that rather than catching the general "Exception" you should consider catching "SpecificBusinessLogicException" instead. Nothing wrong with catching to display a message to the user, but by catching "Exception" you risk catching things you didn't mean to handle.

Comment: there is no handling being done, this is the last line. Either the users get presented with a real error or just "ERROR" (which would be the unhandled error page)

Answer (score -1):

If you feel the need to write such an automated exception handler system you may be over-using exceptions, which could have serious performance implications.

However, this appears to be a generic system for converting exceptions into error codes - so why not just use error codes in the first place? Or learn to use exceptions more effectively so you don't feel the need to convert them into error codes? The fact that you are trying to convert them to something else should raise alarms and suggest to you that you're missing the point somewhere.

Comment: -1 i'm not converting exceptions to error codes, I'm allowing the user to get a real error message instead of redirecting them to "ERROR" for an internal app

Comment: @Chris Marisic: It's not really very good etiquette to ask a question and then down-vote people who have tried to help you just because you disagree with their suggestions. Why not just accept the answer(s) that help you, and disregard anything that you don't feel is relevant/correct?

Comment: DV was for the answer of using error codes, error codes are an outdated and dangerous software practice to be used in n-tier software systems.